# Expanded image on mobile devices, background-fixed

Tags: css, mobile, frontend, mobile-devices

I have a problem with the image on main page of my portfolio website. The image is expanded on mobile devices. Here I upload my CSS code.

```
height: 85vh;
min-height: 100%;
background-image: url('./ZdjeciaPortfolio/mainPhoto.jpg');
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

What can I do? I saw other answers on stack, but all doesn't work

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54nSg.png)

Comment: `max-width:100%;`

Comment: What do you mean the image is expanded? Maybe experiment with the background-size: cover. Try some to use inspect in your browser. I think you need to put some extra effort before asking.